# Laravel 5 assets links

Tags: php, laravel

I try include my css or js files to project using:

```
{{ URL::asset('path to css') }}
```

or

```
{!! Html::style("path to css") !!}
```

or similar.

But i always got link from **public** directory.
like so: http://localhost/projectroot/public/assets/style.css

Why that happens and how can i solve this?

Seems to i should move my assets into public ?

Comment: Inside your assets is it style.css?

Comment: its not a problem. assets dir by default outside public dir in laravel.

Comment: What is the path where you save your style.css?

Comment: projectroot\resources\assets\style.css

Comment: Try this: `{!! Html::style('projectroot/resources/assets/style.css') !!}`

Comment: isnt works, path always starts from http://projectroot/public

Comment: The it should be `{!! Html::style('resources/assets/style.css') !!}`

Comment: no, it still http://localhost/projectroot/public/resources/assets/style.css

Comment: When you access that url can you see the css codes?

Comment: The assets folder in the resources directory is for files that need compilation, like views or LESS files. Compiled assets, or plain assets like CSS and JS files should be in `public/assets/`.

Comment: If you use {!! Html::style('resources/assets/style.css') !!} then you need to update dependencies by laravel collective

Answer (score 45):

use the helper `asset('path/to/css')`

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/style.css') }}">
```

assuming that your `assets/style.css` is under public

Answer (score 18):

In the simplest form, assets means JavaScript, CSS, and images which lie directly under the **public directory** and are publicly accessible using a URL.

Laravel provides a helper function, `asset()`, which generates a URL for your assets. You can use this in blade syntax, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{ { asset('js/jquery.js') } }"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't use headings for regular text.It's considered rude (much like typing in allcaps) and makes your posts harder to read.

Answer (score 5):

That's perfectly normal. Your assets should be in the `public` folder. If you look at the `.htaccess` file in there, you'll see this:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This ensures that files located under `/public` are served directly without involving Laravel while all other urls go through `index.php`.

Also, your server configuration should make sure only the `/public` folder is URL-mapped since sensitive info can be leaked via parent paths (e.g. config files) otherwise.

Comment: I understood. Assets folder outside public - its like storage for partials, who should be compiled into all.css for example.
For js  also