# Displaying stored images in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to allow users to create pages to promote events on my website, creating an event requires an image.
I save the images on disk by using this in my Controller:

```
$file = $request->visual;
$ext = $request->visual->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename = time()."_".$request->name.".".$ext;
$path = public_path().'\visuals';
$upload = $file->move($path, $filename);
```

Every image is linked to an event saved in the database, therefore I save the link to the image in my database as a string with

```
$event->visual_url = $path."\\".$filename;
```

Then, when I want to display the visual I use this in my blade.php, $events being all the events fetched from the database with `Event::all();`

```
@foreach $events as $e
<img src="{{ $e->visual_url }}">
@endforeach
```

When I look into my public folder, the file has correctly been saved, and when I print the URL that is inside `$e->visual_url`, the link is correct. If copy/paste it within my browser I can access the file properly.

Now here's the issue, when I go on my website with an apache server to see if everything is working properly, here is the result I get

[image: Broken file ?]

The string inside my `$e->visual_url` variable is: `S:\xampp\htdocs\TIPSHub\public\visuals\1612956401_Test.jpg` which is the correct path

Comment: you need to store `visuals\1612956401_Test.jpg` path `$path = '\visuals';`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my original post, I already do that, corrected it in the post, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

```
// Instead of:

<img src="{{ $e->visual_url }}">

// Try this:

<img src="{{asset('visuals/'. basename($e->visual_url))}}">
```

[Laravel 5 assets links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705709/laravel-5-assets-links)

Comment: You may or may not need to escape the backslashes. i.e `<img src="{{asset('visuals/'. basename( str_replace("\\", "/", $e->visual_url))}}">`